# Don't understand proof of global solution to parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in L^p(0,T;V)$ denote the solution to the parabolic PDE
$$u_t + \Delta u = f\qquad\text{a.e $t \in [0,T]$}$$
where $u_t \in L^q(0,T;V^*).$ We have the usual assumptions on $V \subset H \subset V^*$ and $H$.

Now this PDE has a unique solution, i.e. $u$ is unique.

$T$ is arbitrary, so we have a set of solutions $u_n \in L^p(0,n;V)$ that solve the PDE a.e in $[0,n]$.

Now i read:

> Define
>   $$v(t) = u_n(t) \qquad \text{if $t \leq n$}$$
>   Then $v \in L^p(0,\infty;V)$ solves the PDE on $[0,\infty).$

Is this obvious that it solves the PDE on the real line? furthermore, to show that $v$ has finite norm in $L^p(0,\infty;V)$ am I right that we need a uniform bound independent of $n$ on $u_n$. These a priori estimates come from considering Galerkin method for example, but I thought that the constant depends on the end time, which in this cases happens to be $n$. So I am not sure how to show it has finite norm.

Comment: Where have you found this proof?

Comment: @Tomás It is in book by Boyer, Fabrie "Mathematical Tools for the Study of the Incompressible Navier-Stokes Equations and Related Models", page 361 (Globality of weak solutions).

Comment: The problem there is a particular one. Why do you think that it can be generalized in such way?

Comment: @Tomas I also saw it here: http://www.cs.elte.hu/~simonl/Nonlinear%20PDE's_book_hyperref.pdf

See the last paragraph of the proof of Theorem 11.2 on page 82. Tbh I do not understand that proof; I think there are several typos. But that is a separate thread.

Comment: Well, so I think it is better to concentrate on the Navier Stokes equation. What do you think?

Comment: @Tomás I have not had a chance to go through it. IMO it seems like it should work for the equation I wrote above. The way the authors wrote about it, uniqueness of solution seems enough, in addition to the a priori estimates possible. I will think more..

Comment: I was thinking in something like this: First note that $v\in L^p_{loc}(0,\infty:V)$. The same is true for the derivative. This implies that you  can integrate it against a function with compact support, hence $v$ is indeed a weak solution. Now it remains to show that it is integrable in all $(0,\infty)$. I am refering to the Naviers Stokes case.

Comment: @Tomás How do you define weak derivative when time interval is $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Also are you sure that you want to show $v \in L^p(0,\infty;V)$? In the book BigUser linked it, they only claim $v \in L^p_{loc}(0,\infty;V)$. Maybe global solution is only required to be in this  loc space..

Comment: @aere, my answer was based in the Navier Stokes reference. There, if I am not mistake the definition does not have the word loc.